# Ruby Jekyll highlight {% highlight ruby %} vs backticks ```

Tags: jekyll

Jekyll does not seem to use the markdown code style blocks that github uses even though they're from the same organization.

Seems like jekyll 3 is requiring the usage of {%highlight ruby %}

is there a canonical way to do clean syntax highlighting with jekyll 3?

looks like

```
{% highlight ruby %}
{% raw %}
{% for template in site.templates %}
...
{% endfor %}
{% endhighlight %}
```

and

```
{% codeblock ruby %}
{% raw %}
{% for template in site.templates %}
...
{% endfor %}
{% endcodeblock %}
```

do the same thing!

and backticks are not converting into code blocks

Comment: Have you tried ~~~ ruby and closing it ~~~ ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use [Github Flavored Markdown](https://guides.github.com/features/mastering-markdown/) you can add this to your `_config.yml` file :

```
kramdown:
  # use Github Flavored Markdown
  input: GFM
```

Answer (score 0):

What version of Jekyll are you using?
Jekyll uses GFM-version of Kramdown since v3.1.0

From the codebase of [**`v3.1.0`**](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/blob/v3.1.0/lib/jekyll/configuration.rb#L65-L72):

```
  'kramdown' => {
    'auto_ids'       => true,
    'toc_levels'     => '1..6',
    'entity_output'  => 'as_char',
    'smart_quotes'   => 'lsquo,rsquo,ldquo,rdquo',
    'input'          => "GFM",
    'hard_wrap'      => false,
    'footnote_nr'    => 1
```